# laravel nested route with prefix and resource dosent work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-resource

I have many routes like these :

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/class', 'classController');
Route::get('/dashboard/class/get-by-filter', 'classController@getByFilter');
Route::get('/dashboard/class/get-by-search', 'classController@getBySearch');
...
...

Route::resource('/dashboard/orders', 'OrderController');
Route::get('/dashboard/orders/get-by-filter', 'OrderController@getByFilter');
...
```

now I want to write these with prefix ,group and resources but I have a problem when write like this :

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function()
    {

       Route::prefix('class')->group(function()
         {
            Route::resource('/', 'classController');
            Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'classController@getByFilter');
            Route::get('/get-by-search', 'classController@getBySearch');
         });

       Route::prefix('orders')->group(function()
         {
            Route::resource('/', 'OrderController');
            Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'OrderController@getByFilter');
            Route::get('/get-by-search', 'OrderController@getBySearch');
         });

});
```

why return 404 when I try to access show address like this :

```
example.com/dashboard/orders/4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `resource` instead of `get`

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->group(function()
    {

       Route::prefix('class')->group(function()
         {
            Route::resource('/', 'classController');
            Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'classController@getByFilter');
            Route::get('/get-by-search', 'classController@getBySearch');
         });

       Route::prefix('orders')->group(function()
         {
            Route::resource('/', 'OrderController');
            Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'OrderController@getByFilter');
            Route::get('/get-by-search', 'OrderController@getBySearch');
         });

});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my wrong in type. I do this but It dose not work yet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using group routing like this.

```
<?php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function() {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'class'], function() {
        Route::resource('/', 'classController');
        Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'classController@getByFilter');
        Route::get('/get-by-search', 'classController@getBySearch');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'orders'], function() {
        Route::resource('/', 'OrderController');
        Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'OrderController@getByFilter');
        Route::get('/get-by-search', 'OrderController@getBySearch');
    });
});
```

Try this. May be this will help you.

Comment: thank you for your response. I try this way but it dose not work yet!

Comment: and also run this command on console `php artisan route:list` then this will show you all the routes listing.

Comment: when I run this: php artisan route:list , I can see there is a route like this : /dashboard/orders/{}. but when I type in url get 404 err.

Comment: Firstly clear your `laravel.log` file and run again hit orders url and then check `laravel.log` file. error will be logged there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think i got it, all you need to pass {id} in the url then dd($id) in your controller method.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'dashboard'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'class'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('/', 'classController');
        Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'classController@getByFilter');
        Route::get('/get-by-search', 'classController@getBySearch');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'orders'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('/{id}','classController');
        Route::get('/get-by-filter', 'OrderController@getByFilter');
        Route::get('/get-by-search', 'OrderController@getBySearch');
    });
});
```

I suggest you to use proper namespace and make sure your **classController** redirect to exact method.